# python os.makedirs() doesnt seem to make the final folder in the directory

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm trying to automate creating new folders for me to put files in. I'm using `os.makedirs()` in python. My issue is that when ran, the code runs without errors and all but the last folder is created.

This is obviously an issue I can easily work around, but I have a feeling I am doing something stupid and there is an easy fix.

Extract of my python code:

`os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("data/3/2/4"), exist_ok=True)`

The path `data/3/2` is created but there are no files inside it.

I have tried specifying a file to be created ("data/3/2/4/things.txt") and when this is ran, 4 is created, but `things.txt` is not created inside of it.

Comment: Why are you expecting the newly created directory to contain files? Can you show your attempt to create a file in the directory?

Comment: Thanks, ill just use the string "data/3/2/4" instead of os.path.dirname("data/3/2/4") as that seems to work.

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work as expected if you just append "/" to your path.

os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("data/3/2/4/"), exist_ok=True)

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
file_path = "data/3/2/4/"
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(file_path), exist_ok=True)
```

you may only need to add:

```
with open(file_path, 'w'):
    pass
```

to open and write the file